# Is it possible to apply for a UK visa without being a local resident?

Tags: visas, uk, residency, zimbabwean-citizens

I am a Zimbabwean passport holder travelling to Denmark. I wanted to confirm if it is possible for me to apply for a UK visa while in Denmark?

Comment: Seems to be "yes" if you're asking about a visitor visa: https://ukimmigrationspecialist.com/2012/10/17/where-can-i-submit-my-visa-application-does-this-have-to-be-in-my-home-country/

Answer (score 3):

According to [UkImmigrationSpecialist](https://ukimmigrationspecialist.com/2012/10/17/where-can-i-submit-my-visa-application-does-this-have-to-be-in-my-home-country/):

> Applications for transit visas, visit visas, and EEA Family Permits may be submitted in any country offering a UK Entry Clearance (=visa) service.

So the answer is: **yes**, you may submit your application in Denmark. However be aware that you'll have to receive your visa in Denmark as well and cannot receive it back in Zimbabwe.