# Can you apply for a UK Visa in a location that is not your residence?

Tags: visas, uk, applications

I know the UK visa is applied for online, but you will have to appear somewhere for biometric capturing. Can you give this biometric information in a location that is not your residence (as in another country?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to apply for a UK visa without being a local resident?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/76583/is-it-possible-to-apply-for-a-uk-visa-without-being-a-local-resident)

Comment: How you provide biometrics depends on where you’re from and what type of passport you have, it is done either in person at an appointment at a visa application centre, or via the ‘UK Immigration: ID Check’ smartphone app https://www.gov.uk/apply-to-come-to-the-uk/prove-your-identity

Comment: @Traveller The cited question is only a duplicate if "giving biometrics" (the OP's concern here) is the same as "receiving the visa" as used in the cited question. Without further clarity in the other question, which is unlikely after 5+ years, I don't it can be considered duplicate.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica The info in the suggested duplicate is still valid, however I’ve found the official source so will post an answer

Answer (score 3):

Yes, depending on the type of visa you are applying for.

Providing you are *present legally* in the country or territory you’re applying from, you can apply for a visit visa, a short-term study visa, International Sportsperson, Temporary Work – Creative Worker, Youth Mobility Scheme and Global Talent entry clearance in any visa application centre, British diplomatic mission or consular post overseas where entry clearance applications are accepted.

Applications for other types of entry clearance should be made in the country where you’re living.

Source: https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/where-to-apply-ecb05/ecb5-where-to-apply-the-policy